# Why can plants handle extra chromosomes much better than animals?

Tags: chromosome

Why can plants handle being polyploid way better than animals, where it is almost always fatal?
I found a 2004 paper while searching about this topic, but I'm wondering if there have been any recent discoveries and if scientists are still actively looking for a definitive answer.